# Location.reload (true) just spinning but won't reload the page

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication

I am trying to logout the user from my application and  I have a button listening for a click event to perform the logout algorithm which looks something like the below code however I only see the spinning wheel and nothing.

```
export const logout = async () => {
  try {
    const res = await axios({
      method: "GET",
      url: "http://localhost:3001/users/logout",
    });
    console.log(res)
     if ((res.data.status === "success")) {
      window.setTimeout(() => {
      location.reload(true);
      }, 1000)
     }
   
  } catch (err) {
    showAlert("error", "Error!! Logging out ! Please Try Again");
  }
};
```

Console.log returns everything as expected ---
[Console Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3eBVR.png)

Comment: please share the logout function,

Comment: Is your `res.data.status` really equal to `"success"`? Also, are you sending an object from your server with the `status` property?

Comment: Did you inspect the xhr in the browser's dev tools? Does the axios request go through? What is the reply? What you describe is what happens when `res.data.status` isn't `"success"`.

Comment: @MoniruzzamanMonir -  if (logOut) { 
  logOut.addEventListener("click", logout);
}.             // logOut = document.getElementByID

Comment: @DDomen - Yes, I checked at the console and I get all the data. Instead of reloading the page if pass like an alert() function it does alert me. Basically, the location. reload(true)is not working for some reason

Comment: I have added the image of the Console. I hope it will make some sense now. Thank you all for the help

Comment: @ChrisG, request works. I have added the picture if you could have a look, it would be great. Moreover, I am not sure what do you mean by res. data.status inst ``` success ```

Comment: write `res.data.data.status === 'success'`hope it will fix it

Comment: Are you positive the page doesn't reload? I assume you're expecting the page to change to a logged out state, but if the error is in your server-side code and the user isn't actually logged out, reloading the page might not cause any visible change.

Comment: @SulavDahal did you check `res.data.data.status === 'success'`? According to your console image, only `res.data.status` should be `200` and you should go deeper inside it should be `res.data.data.status` to get access of `success`

Comment: @ChrisG Yup, Page won't reload with the location.reload()  code however If I would manually reload myself it will log me out, so I don't think there is an error in server-side code. When I use the javascript built-in method to reload the page it will just keep spinning however if I would refresh the page on my own, it logs out.

Comment: @MoniruzzamanMonir, Unfortunately, that doesn't work.

Comment: @SulavDahal what is your response from server? it should be like `res.status(200).json({ status: 'success' });` share this, if you use this line as same then you can catch it via `res.data.status` or you can use this function as `if (res.data.status === 'success') location.assign('/');` try location.assign.

Comment: Try to: 1) put `location.reload()` outside the `setTimeout`, 2) `try/catch` it inside the timeout, 3) `console.log` something after it. `location.reload` is origin protected to prevent  script injection, maybe you get an error and you don't catch it

Comment: @DDomen I tried that step as well, but nothing seems to work

Comment: @MoniruzzamanMonir, The response from the server looks like the attached image. When I use the javascript built-in method to reload the page i.e location.reload() it will just keep spinning (won't do anything) however if I would refresh the page on my own, it logs out. Furthermore, I don't see any errors in my console as well. I tried the location.assing('/) it does nothing. To log in the user I have used location.assign() it works but log out doesn't work.